# CSS: different certain width for child elements

Tags: html, css

I've got unordered-list.

- Home
- Blog
- About
- Contact

How i can set different width property for each child of ul, if there is no way to set class or id property for li?
Final result should be something like this:
/*****52px*****/ /*******100px*********//*****92px*****/ /*******150px*********/

Comment: In addition to these guys `:nth-child()` answers you might want to check this out for better browser support http://sizzlejs.com/

Comment: css3 pseudo-classes have very limited browser compatibility [LINK](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS3 [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/nthchild.html) is a good info about what you need [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3anth-child). For fail safety, because not every browser supports CSS3, in addition you can assign id with a property to the elements of ul.

Comment: this works only in latest browsers, making it useless in most cases... and if you can assign id, there is no reason to use that pseudo-class

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bakudan, it works

-- HTML

Home

Blog

About

Contact

-- CSS

```
.menu li:nth-child(1){
color:green;
width:52px;    
}
```

Have a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/geekonweb/WZEGk/